# Outlook reports "no default gateway" on Lan Domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I have a local domain with DC win2003 and an exchange server also added to the domain.
When I connect a pc to the domain and put the ip , mask and DNS (the same as DC), outlook dont get directly the users credentials to log him in.
I manage to resolve it adding a default gateway to NIC's the ip of the exchange server.

This approach is wrong and I have to face it now that I really need a default gateway to an other network. 
What do I do wrong? With my little experience I believe is the DNS server fault. 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This is very not clear, but sounds like you want to add a route with to this other network, instead of changing the default gateway.

Comment: My problem is not not to fix the other network... but why should in a local network be a default gateway (with the ip of Exchange server) for it to work as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a common issue with Outlook 2007 and later](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913843/en-us) (I suppose you use one of these versions, because Outlook 2003 doesn't have these problems).

It requires  a default gateway to be set.

Try the registry fix or use the "Fix it" from MS, I'd say.

Comment: Yes...this is the message I get..."Outlook cannot log on. Verify that you are connected to the network and are using the proper server and mailbox name. The connection to the Microsoft Exchange Server is unavailable. Your network adapter does not have a default gateway."